# mostrar imagen dentro de mi interfaz pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv

He creado un programa bastante absurdo mediante `pyqt5` y `opencv`.

Lo que hace es obtener una imagen, convertirla a escala de grises, guardarla y mostrarla en una ventana aparte. Pero, a mi me gustaría que se mostrase en mi propia interfaz, concretamente en el cuadrado superior que se ve en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto que se puede hace mediante `label` pero no me aclaro, ¿me podeis ayudar a ello?

Código entero:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'pruebaqt.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import cv2 as cv

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(639, 554)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 410, 621, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 611, 391))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 639, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        #
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.image)
        #
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PRUEBA"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Escala de grises"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

    #
    def image(self):
        img = cv.imread('img.png',0)
        cv.imwrite('ss.png', img)
        cv.imshow('sss', img)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Por lo tanto la parte "conflictiva" es:

```
#
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.image)
#

#
def image(self):
    img = cv.imread('img.png',0)
    cv.imwrite('ss.png', img)
    cv.imshow('sss', img)
```

**EDICIÓN**

Siguiendo los consejos de la respuesta de Saelyth, ya se colocar una imagen en qt designer. Esta ya ocupa el lugar deseado.

Ahora el problema es que al convertir el `.ui` a `.py`, da error y ya no sale.

En la función `retranslateUi` hay una linea nueva:

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Escala de grises"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/chchch/img.png\"/></p></body></html>"))
```

Y se me genera un `import` para la imagen que es donde se me genera el error:

```
 import noe_rc
```

¿A que se debe el error si la imagen sigue en la misma ruta?

Comment: Buenas, te retorna algun error?

Comment: Para tu ultimo error debes tener un .qrc a .py usando: `pyrcc5 noe.qrc -o noe_rc.py `

Answer (score 1):

yo no uso los LayoutBox desde el Qt Designer porque me dan muchos problemas, llevo años haciendo interfaces sin Layouts de ese tipo simplemente con el Designer y no tengo problemas. No obstante, imagino que si creas un label dentro de tu layout, alterarlo luego es sencillo. Lo explico:

Para el tema de imagenes, con un QLabel fijo las puedes añadir mediante el Qt Designer: 
[image: Ejemplo]

En esa imagen he creado dos QLabels, y la única diferencia entre uno y otro es que al de abajo le he asignado un PixMap (haces click donde he puesto la flecha, eliges File... y listo).

Mediante código si quieres cambiar la imagen, sería de esta manera:

```
imagen = QtWidgets.QPixmap("miarchivo.png")
self.nombredellabel.setPixmap(imagen)
```

*Nota: Todos mis ejemplos son de PySide2 y no PyQt5, pero deberían funcionar casi iguales.*

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Ahora me error al convertir al archivo a python, si supieras la respuesta te lo agradecería muchísimo y si no gracias igualmente. :)

Comment: A qué te refieres, al transformar el archivo .ui? Para eso si usas pyside2-uic basta con ejecutar en CMD: `pyside2-uic archivo.ui -o archivoenpython.py` No sé como será en Pyqt. Si esto no es lo que querías te sugiero cerrar esta pregunta y abrir una nueva.